# Huffman tree Python implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, compression

```
"""
### General Idea:

Given a set of n character set C.

1. Begin with a set of |C| leaves.
2. Repeatedly using **min-priority** queue `Q`, keyed on frequencies,
   identify the two least-frequent objects to merge together.
3. Until all be merged.

### Input

List of tuple containing frequency and character.

### Output

A tree T, called Huffman tree.
"""

import heapq


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key, freq, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = key
        self.freq = freq
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.freq, other.freq)

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0}, {1})".format(self.key, self.freq)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

def encode(rel_freq):
    nodes = create_leaf_nodes(rel_freq)
    heapq.heapify(nodes)
    root = build_encode_tree(nodes)
    #print_tree(root)
    return root

def create_leaf_nodes(rel_freq):
    return map(lambda (freq, key): Node(key, freq), rel_freq)

def merge(n1, n2):
    freq = n1.freq + n2.freq
    if n1.freq <= n2.freq:
        return Node(n1.key + n2.key, freq, n1, n2)
    return Node(n2.key + n1.key, freq, n2, n1)

def build_encode_tree(nodes):
    root = nodes[0]
    while len(nodes) > 1:
        n1 = heapq.heappop(nodes)
        n2 = heapq.heappop(nodes)
        root = merge(n1, n2)
        heapq.heappush(nodes, root)
    return root

# ---------------- Helpers --------------------------
def print_tree(root):
    for nodes in level_order(root):
        for node in nodes:
            print node,
        print

def level_order(node):
  """Given Binary Tree gives list nodes in each level."""
  current_level = [node]
  while current_level:
    yield current_level
    next_level = []
    for node in current_level:
      if node.left:
        next_level.append(node.left)
      if node.right:
        next_level.append(node.right)
    current_level = next_level

import unittest


class TestHuffmanEncoding(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_single_char(self):
        rel_freq = [(24, 'A')]
        actual = str(encode(rel_freq))
        self.assertEqual(actual, "(A, 24)")

    def test_valid_encoding(self):
        #expected = [('A', '0'), ('B', '100'), ('C', '101'), ('D', '110'), ('E', '111')]
        rel_freq = [(24, 'A'), (12, 'B'), (10, 'C'), (8, 'D'), (8, 'E')]
        expected = "(AEDCB, 62)"
        actual = str(encode(rel_freq))
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

        rel_freq = [(45, 'A'), (13, 'B'), (12, 'C'), (16, 'D'), (9, 'E'), (5, 'F')]
        expected = "(ACBFED, 100)"
        actual = str(encode(rel_freq))
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

#### Note:

The code do generate the Huffman tree but I am more interested in finding the encoding of each character, the basic approach what I think is traversing each path from root to leaf such that moving left adds `0` to the path and moving right adds `1`. Hopefully I would post the solution soon in another review.

Answer (score 4):

Merging is a thing a node and only a node does, using that function on a non-node is meaningless so include it in the node class:

```
class Node:
    ...
    def merge(self, other_node):
```

Now the person that uses your code knows that merge works for nodes and nothing else and the code has more structure.

Comment: Hmm, I am confused with the concept of [parametric polymerphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), when to apply this concept?

Comment: @CodeYogi i do not mean enforcing type safety, just hinting at the way to use it.

Comment: Cool! it seems that I am learning alot, now my code seems to have lot less comments :), but I am still confused about the `__repr__` stuff, you gave me some comment in my previous post by it was not clear.

Comment: If what if I want to merge objects which behaves like node, why bound my method to just one type?

Comment: @CodeYogi You are not bounding yourself